# No se me actualizan los datos de la tabla Mysql usando una sentencia en PHP

Tags: php, sql, update

Estoy intentando que a través de una sentencia sql en un código Php se me actualice una tabla, por alguna razón no sucede. La idea es que al insertar el ID me traiga los datos a través de una function de JS, eso sucede, y  luego me permita actualizarlos cambiando los datos que me trajo y luego dando click al button "actualizar" que lleva a una sentencia de Mysql, y al hacerlo todo parece funcionar pero los datos no se actualizan, ni siquiera me tira un error, entonces no se cual es el problema.

Aquí el codigo Php: ProcesoWebUPD.php

```
    <?php
    // PROCESO WEB MARKET UPD

    // conectar al servidor
    include "conexion.inc";
    // capturar datos del formulario
    $id          = $_POST["ID"];
    $marca       = utf8_decode($_POST["MARC"]);
    $descripcion = utf8_decode($_POST["DESC"]);
    $origen      = utf8_decode($_POST["ORIG"]);
    $categoria   = utf8_decode($_POST["CAT"]);
    // sentencia SQL para INSERTAR registro
    $sql  = "UPDATE productos SET ";
    $sql .= "marcPROD = '$marca', ";
    $sql .= "descPROD = '$descripcion', ";
    $sql .= "origPROD = '$origen', ";
    $sql .= "nomCAT   = $categoria ";            
    $sql .= "WHERE idPROD=$id";
    // depurar sentencia SQL
    // die($sql);
    // ejecutar sentencia SQL
    mysql_query($sql,$conex);
    // cerrar conexión
    mysql_close($conex);
    // volver automáticamente al formulario
    header("location: FormWebUPD.php");
    ?>
```

Aquí el código JS donde envío los datos actualizados:

```
/* FUNCIONES PARA SISTEMA WEB MARKET */
function CheckForm() {
    // crear mensaje y control de error
    var mensaje = "ATENCION!!!... Ingrese:\n";
    var error   = false;
    // capturar datos del formulario
    var marca       = document.getElementById("marcPROD").value;
    var descripcion = document.getElementById("descPROD").value;
    var origen      = document.getElementById("origPROD").value;
    var precio      = document.getElementById("costPROD").value;
    var categoria   = document.getElementById("catPROD").value;
    // validar datos
    if (marca=="") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Marca:\n";
    } // endif
    if (descripcion=="") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Descripción:\n";
    } // endif
    if (origen=="0") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Origen:\n";
    } // endif
    if (precio=="") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Precio:\n";
    } // endif
    if (isNaN(precio)) {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Precio debe ser numérico:\n";
    } // endif        
    if (categoria=="0") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"Categoría:\n";
    } // endif
    // controlar error 
    if (error) {
        // enviar mensjae de error
        window.alert(mensaje);
    } else {
        // enviar formulario
        document.getElementById("dataFRM").submit();
    } // endif
} // end function

function CheckID() {
    // crear mensaje y control de error
    var mensaje = "ATENCION!!!... Ingrese:\n";
    var error   = false;
    // capturar datos del formulario
    var id = document.getElementById("idPROD").value;
    // validar datos
    if (id=="") {
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"ID no puede ser vacío:\n";
    } // endif
    if (isNaN(id)) {    // is Not a Number
        error   = true;
        mensaje = mensaje+"ID debe ser numérico:\n";
    } // endif
    // controlar error 
    if (error) {
        // enviar mensjae de error
        window.alert(mensaje);
    } else {
        // enviar formulario
        document.getElementById("dataFRM").submit();
    } // endif
} // end function

function SetPage(url) {
    // cargar la url especificada
    window.location = url;
} // end function
```

Aquí el formulario: FormWebUPD.php

```
<div id="contenido">
  <fieldset id="fldFRM">
      <legend>Actualizar</legend>
      <form id="dataFRM" action="ProcesoWebConfirmUPD.php" method="POST">
      <table id="tblFRM">
      <tr>
              <td>ID:</td>
                <td>
                  <input id="idPROD" 
                         type="text" 
                         name="ID" 
                         maxlength="5" 
                         title="máximo 5 dígitos"
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>       
      <tr>
          <td>Marca:</td>
          <td>
              <input id="marcPROD" 
                     type="text" 
                     name="MARC"
                     maxlength="50"
                     title="máximo 20 caracteres"
                     disabled
                     value="deshabilitado"
              />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Descripción:</td>
            <td>
              <input id="descPROD" 
                     type="text" 
                     name="DESC"
                     maxlength="100"
                     title="máximo 100 caracteres"   
                     disabled
                     value="deshabilitado"                  
              />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Origen:</td>
            <td>
              <select id="origPROD" name="ORIG" disabled>
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione Origen --</option>
                <option value="Alemania">Alemania</option> 
                <option value="Japón">Japón</option> 
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
              <?php
                include "LoadORIG.inc";
              ?>
              </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Precio:</td>
            <td>
              <input id="costPROD" 
                     type="text" 
                     name="COST" 
                     maxlength="10" 
                     disabled
                     value="deshabilitado"                  
              />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Categoría:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="catPROD" name="CAT" disabled>
                    <option value="0">-- Seleccione Categoría --</option>\n";
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- botones del formulario -->
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
              <input type="button" value="Confirmar" 
               onclick="CheckID();"/>
              <input type="reset"  value="Cancelar" />
            </td>
        </tr>          
        </table>
      </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Aquí el Php del segundo formulario que recoge el ID: ProcesoWebConfirmUPD.php

```
<?php
    // PROCESO WEB MARKET CONFIRM UPD

    // conectar al Servidor de Base de Datos
    include "conexion.inc";
    // capturar ID a buscar desde el formulario
    $id = $_POST["ID"];
    // crear sentencia SQL para buscar el ID
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE idPROD=$id";
    // ejecutar sentecia SQL
    $result = mysql_query($sql,$conex);
    // controlar existencia
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) {
        // mensaje de error
        header("location:errorPage.php?MSG=ID INEXISTENTE");
    } else {
        // cargar registro
        $regPROD = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        // convertir datos
        $id          = $regPROD["idPROD"];
        $marca       = utf8_encode($regPROD["marcPROD"]);
        $descripcion = utf8_encode($regPROD["descPROD"]);
        $origen      = $regPROD["origPROD"];
        $precio      = $regPROD["costPROD"];
        $categoria   = $regPROD["catPROD"];
    } // endif
?>

<div id="contenido">
  <fieldset id="fldFRM">
      <legend>Actualizar</legend>
      <form id="dataFRM" action="ProcesoWebUPD.php" method="POST">
        <table id="tblFRM">
            <tr>
                <td>ID:</td>
                <td>
                  <input id="idPROD" 
                         type="text" 
                         name="ID"
                         maxlength="5"
                         title="deshabilitado"
                         readonly
                <?php 
                    echo "value='$id'";
                ?>
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>            
            <tr>
              <td>Marca:</td>
              <td>
                <input id="marcPROD" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="MARC"
                       maxlength="50"
                       title="máximo 50 caracteres"
                <?php 
                    echo "value='$marca'";
                ?>
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Descripción:</td>
              <td>
                <input id="descPROD" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="DESC"
                       maxlength="100"
                       title="máximo 100 caracteres"                     
                <?php 
                    echo "value='$descripcion'";
                ?>
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td>Origen:</td>
             <td>
              <select id="origPROD" name="ORIG">
                <option value="0">-- Seleccione Origen --</option>
                <option value="Alemania">Alemania</option> 
                <option value="Japón">Japón</option> 
                <option value="USA">USA</option>
              <?php
                include "LoadORIG.inc";
              ?>
             </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Precio:</td>
              <td>
                <input id="costPROD" 
                       type="text" 
                       name="COST"
                       maxlength="50"
                <?php 
                    echo "value=$precio";
                ?>
                />
              </td>
          </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Categoría:</td>
              <td>
               <select id="catPROD" name="CAT">
                 <option value="0">-- Seleccione Categoría --</option>\n";
                 <?php
                   include "LoadCATsel.inc";
                 ?>
               </select>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- botones del formulario -->
            <tr>
              <td colspan="2">
                <input type="button" value="Actualizar"  onclick="CheckForm();"/>
                <input type="button" value="Cancelar"    onclick="SetPage('FormWebUPD.php');"/>
              </td>
            </tr>          
          </table>


      </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Las funciones `mysql_` son obsoletas desde hace años, desde la [versión 5.5 y eliminadas en la 7.0](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-close.php) en adelante... seguro que eso lo tienes controlado?

Comment: Vale, ahora lo entiendo mejor... he tenido que crear esto para comprenderlo y verlo bien: https://jsfiddle.net/qp6k8vj3/